# Mapbox get latitude and longitude from device precise location

Tags: android, location, mapbox

I'm using mapbox sdk 0.5.0 and I successfully draw my location on the mapview. But when I try to get my precise location, the coordinate return from `GpsLocationProvider` or `UserLocationOverlay` is different from the coordinate drawn on the mapview. This is the method to get my location :

```
private void GetMyLocation(){
    gpsLocationProvider = new GpsLocationProvider(ShowMap.this);
    userLocationOverlay = new UserLocationOverlay(gpsLocationProvider, mapview);
    userLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    userLocationOverlay.setDrawAccuracyEnabled(true);
    mapview.getOverlays().add(userLocationOverlay);
    mapview.setCenter(userLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
    mapview.setUserLocationRequiredZoom(10);

    Marker marker = new Marker(mapview, "", "", new LatLng(userLocationOverlay.getLastFix().getLatitude(), userLocationOverlay.getLastFix().getLongitude()));
    mapview.addMarker(marker);
}
```

Here is the screenshot of my app. The circle marker is my precise location and the black marker is the location from `getLastFix`. [image] 
I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is a bit of disconnect between instantiating the UserLocationOverlay directly versus using the infrastructure bundled into the MapView.  Give the following a try instead:

```
// Setup UserLocation monitoring
MapView mv = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.locateMeMapView);
mv.setUserLocationEnabled(true);
mv.setUserLocationTrackingMode(UserLocationOverlay.TrackingMode.FOLLOW);
mv.setUserLocationRequiredZoom(10);

// Retrieve UserLocation
mv.getUserLocation();
```

Comment: this is not working as close as Google Map is there any types of map that i can set to mapBox ..... so that user can see location more close ....moreover i m using this code and giving me error mapView.setTileSource(new MapboxTileLayer("examples.map-vyofok3q"));     Error   :

Comment: 05-16 12:54:50.568: E/WebSourceTileLayer(8550): Error downloading MapTile: https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/examples.map-vyofok3q/17/89972/56169.png?access_token=sk.eyJ1IjoiZXJ1bWhhbm5hbiIsImEiOiJpNHBqYkxrIn0.GEpxtSoZ7u8X7UXS5SJ15Q:java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/examples.map-vyofok3q/17/89972/56169.png?access_token=sk.eyJ1IjoiZXJ1bWhhbm5hbiIsImEiOiJpNHBqYkxrIn0.GEpxtSoZ7u8X7UXS5SJ15Q

Comment: i do not want to show user location in mapview ..... but i want to get current latitude and longitude how is it possible from mapbox ?

Comment: @Erum The best bet is to use the stock Android Location APIs then to get user location.